# Если не прошла одна авторизация как перейти на другую? Spring Security

Tags: spring, авторизация, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

На проекте нужно реализовать авторизацию с помощью Kerberos и чтобы она по приоритету была первая, т.е. изначально при переходе пользователя по ссылке someproject.com шла авторизация через Kerberos и в случае, если его учетной записи нет в AD, то его переводило на форму ввода логина и пароля someproject.com/login. На данный момент удалось реализовать Kerberos, он работает, но тогда не работает форма ввода логина и пароля, т.е. не переводит на форму логина и пароля(например для линуксовых пользователей). Подскажите как правильно настроить Spring Security. Перепробовал много способов.

Привожу часть конфигурации:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(authenticationEntryPoint, new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/file/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/company/*/portals").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/portal/logo/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**", "/ticket/otId/*").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ARTICLE_EDITOR", "NEWS_EDITOR", "CATALOG_EDITOR", "CATALOG_OBSERVER")
                .antMatchers("/support**").hasRole("SUPPORT")
                .antMatchers("/redirect**").authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                .usernameParameter(LOGIN_PARAM)
                .passwordParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM)
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_PAGE_URL)
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter(REMEMBER_ME_PARAM)
                .rememberMeCookieName(REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_NAME)
                .tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1))
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider)
                .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());

        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/")
                .antMatchers("/static/**")
                .antMatchers("/js/**")
                .antMatchers("/css/**")
                .antMatchers("/tpl/**")
                .antMatchers("/error/**")
                .antMatchers("/component/**")
                .antMatchers("/images/**")

                .antMatchers("/index.html")
                .antMatchers("/login.html")
                .antMatchers("/*.ico");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(@Qualifier("restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
                                                                               AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint) {

        RequestMatcher restMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**");

        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map =
                new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
        map.put(restMatcher, restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(map);
        delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            String cookieValue = URLEncoder.encode("{\"method\":\"" + httpServletRequest.getMethod() + "\",\"url\":\"" + httpServletRequest.getRequestURL() + "\"}", "UTF-8");
            httpServletResponse.addCookie(new Cookie(REDIRECT_COOKIE_NAME, cookieValue));
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(LOGIN_PAGE_URL);
        });
        return delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

@Bean
    public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
        return new SpnegoEntryPoint("/");
    }
```

Еще раз поясню:

При данной конфигурации получается если я захожу с линукса по ссылке someproject.com то просто ничего не происходит, я так и остаюсь не авторизованным и автоматически меня никуда не редиректит(вообщем просто белый экран),но если я сам в адресной строке не наберу someproject.com/login то переходит на форму авторизации ввожу логин и пароль и меня авторизовывает в приложении.

Если заходит виндовый пользователь по ссылке someproject.com то его авторизует и он уже может работать с приложением.